# Callback from PHPUnit functions

Tags: php, phpunit

I would like to build a simple application to test API's and take further action (such as notifying myself with an email) if the returned object is faulty.

PHPUnit's assert methods seem just right for testing the API's. However, I wonder if I could run these methods in a code level rather than in a command line.

So here is the question:

How can I use PHPUnit's assert methods in my code with custom callbacks?

Comment: Keep in mind, then testing at runtime will have an overhead cost of performing the tests.  You are best to test outside the main application, then when code works with your API, it is not slowed down and effecting performance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I should have looked into PHP manual first. Here are links to helpful functions for this question:

1. http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.assert.php
2. http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.assert-options.php

Comment: Note that this assert function is not the same as the PHPUnit ones. This function expects a string with PHP code inside, which will get executed if assertions are enabled. So you would use it on the development and test system, but not in production. And it isn't a replacement for testing the software from the outside (unit, integration, functional test), it is a different approach. It is testing from the inside.